# Pegar conteúdo via DIV, usando o bootstrap-wysiwyg-master e enviando via $_POST

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

Estou criando meu bootstrap-wysiwyg-master, e preciso que a DIV onde fica o conteúdo do texto, seja enviado via POST em PHP, que que eu possa inclui-lo no banco de dados etc... Segue abaixo o código do form que estou usando:

```
<form method="POST" action="teste.php" name="form_redacao" id="form_redacao" onsubmit="return enviardados();" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate></form>
```

Em seguida, após os botoes de edição, vem a DIV que recebe o conteúdo editado:

```
<div name="editor" id="editor">
  Escreva seu texto...
</div>
```

E por fim o botão que irá submeter essas informações e enviar via POST para teste.php.

Agora o script que ajudaria no resgate dos dados:

```
<script>
$('#btn-enviar').click(function(){    
    alert($(this).parents('div #editor').attr('getText'));
    $('#form_redacao').submit();    
});
</script>
```

A página teste.php só tem o POST para teste de execução, daí pra frente eu adiciono o conteúdo no banco:

```
<?php
   echo $_POST['editor'];
?>
```

Obs.: no momento não faz nada. A ideia é poder pegar esses dados e gravar no banco de dados e daí posteriormente poder atualizar, excluir etc. Seria para um uso de um painel adm, coisa simples.

Código completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tiny, opensource, Bootstrap WYSIWYG rich text editor from MindMup</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="opensource rich wysiwyg text editor jquery bootstrap execCommand html5" />
    <meta name="description" content="This tiny jQuery Bootstrap WYSIWYG plugin turns any DIV into a HTML5 rich text editor" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="//mindmup.s3.amazonaws.com/lib/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://mindmup.s3.amazonaws.com/lib/img/favicon.ico" >
    <link href="external/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="external/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="external/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>

    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="personalizado.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <script src="bootstrap-wysiwyg.js"></script>    


  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="teste.php" name="form_redacao" id="form_redacao" onsubmit="return enviardados();" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>

    <div class="hero-unit">

        <div id="alerts"></div>
        <div class="btn-toolbar" data-role="editor-toolbar" data-target="#editor">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font"><i class="icon-font"></i><b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              </ul>
            </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font Size"><i class="icon-text-height"></i>&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a data-edit="fontSize 6"><font size="6">Grande</font></a></li>
              <li><a data-edit="fontSize 4"><font size="4">Normal</font></a></li>
              <li><a data-edit="fontSize 2"><font size="2">Pequeno</font></a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn" data-edit="bold" title="Bold (Ctrl/Cmd+B)"><i class="icon-bold"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-edit="italic" title="Italic (Ctrl/Cmd+I)"><i class="icon-italic"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-edit="strikethrough" title="Strikethrough"><i class="icon-strikethrough"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-edit="underline" title="Underline (Ctrl/Cmd+U)"><i class="icon-underline"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn" data-edit="insertunorderedlist" title="Bullet list"><i class="icon-list-ul"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-edit="insertorderedlist" title="Number list"><i class="icon-list-ol"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-edit="outdent" title="Reduce indent (Shift+Tab)"><i class="icon-indent-left"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-edit="indent" title="Indent (Tab)"><i class="icon-indent-right"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyleft" title="Align Left (Ctrl/Cmd+L)"><i class="icon-align-left"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-edit="justifycenter" title="Center (Ctrl/Cmd+E)"><i class="icon-align-center"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyright" title="Align Right (Ctrl/Cmd+R)"><i class="icon-align-right"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyfull" title="Justify (Ctrl/Cmd+J)"><i class="icon-align-justify"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
              <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Inserir Hyperlink"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu input-append">
                    <strong>Inserir </strong>
                    <input class="span2" placeholder="URL" type="text" data-edit="createLink"/>
                    <button class="btn" type="button"> Adicionar </button>
            </div>
            <a class="btn" data-edit="unlink" title="Remover Hyperlink"><i class="icon-cut"></i></a>

          </div>

          <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn" title="Inserir Imagem (ou assante e solte)" id="pictureBtn"><i class="icon-picture"></i></a>
            <input type="file" data-role="magic-overlay" data-target="#pictureBtn" data-edit="insertImage" />
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn" data-edit="undo" title="voltar (Ctrl/Cmd+Z)"><i class="icon-undo"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-edit="redo" title="seguir (Ctrl/Cmd+Y)"><i class="icon-repeat"></i></a>
          </div>
          <input type="text" data-edit="inserttext" id="voiceBtn" x-webkit-speech="">
        </div>

        <textarea name="editor" style="display: none;"></textarea>


        <div id="editor">
          Escreva seu texto...
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-enviar" value="Mostrar Resultado">    
    </form>

</div>
</body>
<script>
$('#btn-enviar').click(function(){    
    alert($(this).parents('div#editor').attr('getText'));

    //$("[name=editor]").val($(this).parents('div#editor').attr('getText'));

    // aqui vc atualiza o textarea antes do submit
    //$("[name=editor]").val($(this).parents('div#editor').attr('getText'));

    //$("[name=editor]").val($('#editor').html());

    $('#form_redacao').submit();    
});
</script> 

<script>    




  $(function(){
    function initToolbarBootstrapBindings() {
      var fonts = ['Serif', 'Sans', 'Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Courier', 
            'Courier New', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Helvetica', 'Impact', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', 'Tahoma', 'Times',
            'Times New Roman', 'Verdana'],
            fontTarget = $('[title=Font]').siblings('.dropdown-menu');
      $.each(fonts, function (idx, fontName) {
          fontTarget.append($('<li><a data-edit="fontName ' + fontName +'" style="font-family:\''+ fontName +'\'">'+fontName + '</a></li>'));
      });
      $('a[title]').tooltip({container:'body'});
        $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function() {return false;})
            .change(function () {$(this).parent('.dropdown-menu').siblings('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');})
        .keydown('esc', function () {this.value='';$(this).change();});

      $('[data-role=magic-overlay]').each(function () { 
        var overlay = $(this), target = $(overlay.data('target')); 
        overlay.css('opacity', 0).css('position', 'absolute').offset(target.offset()).width(target.outerWidth()).height(target.outerHeight());
      });
      if ("onwebkitspeechchange"  in document.createElement("input")) {
        var editorOffset = $('#editor').offset();
        $('#voiceBtn').css('position','absolute').offset({top: editorOffset.top, left: editorOffset.left+$('#editor').innerWidth()-35});
      } else {
        $('#voiceBtn').hide();
      }
    };
    function showErrorAlert (reason, detail) {
        var msg='';
        if (reason==='unsupported-file-type') { msg = "Unsupported format " +detail; }
        else {
            console.log("error uploading file", reason, detail);
        }
        $('<div class="alert"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+ 
         '<strong>File upload error</strong> '+msg+' </div>').prependTo('#alerts');
    };
    initToolbarBootstrapBindings();  
    $('#editor').wysiwyg({ fileUploadError: showErrorAlert} );
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
  });

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-37452180-6', 'github.io');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


  !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um `textarea` oculto no form. Ao fazer o submit, jogue o conteúdo da div do editor nesse `textarea`.

Retire o `name="editor"` da div e coloque no `textarea`:

```
<div id="editor">
  Escreva seu texto...
</div>

<form method="POST" action="teste.php" name="form_redacao" id="form_redacao" onsubmit="return enviardados();" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>

   <textarea name="editor" style="display: none;"></textarea>
   <input type="button" id="btn-enviar" value="Enviar">

</form>

<script>
$('#btn-enviar').click(function(){    

    // aqui vc atualiza o textarea antes do submit
    $("[name=editor]").val($("#editor").html());

    $('#form_redacao').submit();    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sam, o que ocorre quando faço essa solicitação que me sugeriu é que o alert me exibe um valor undefined. e tem mais um detalhe... quando troco a tag div por textarea  as feferramentas do bootstrap-wysiwyg, passam a não funcionar

Comment: Não é pra trocar a div por textarea, a resposta não diz isso :)... Tente trocando isso `$("[name=editor]").val($(this).parents('div#editor').attr('getText'));` por isto `$("[name=editor]").val($('#editor').html());`

Comment: me expressei mal.. quiz dique que fiz uma tentativa antes de mudar o div por um textarea mais quanod o fiz as ferramentas do bootstrap-wysiwyg, passaram a não quer funcionar..

Comment: quanto a arrumação de código que vc fez acima tenho uma duvida ! esse div é para ficar fora da tag form mesmo ? porque atualmente estou pondo dentro..

Comment: Pode deixar dentro ou fora, não faz diferença.

Comment: acabei de fazer o teste aqui, sem sucesso.. =/

Comment: coloquei no topo do post o código completo.. talvez e esteja deixando algo de importante de lado..

Comment: vou dar uma olhada...

Comment: Testei aqui e é isso mesmo: o texto do editor vc pega com `$("#editor").html()`

Comment: funcionou usando essa aqui: <div name="editor" id="editor" class="editor">Escreva seu texto...</div> <textarea name="titulo-redacao" id="titulo-redacao" style=""></textarea>$("#redacao").text($("#editor").html());

Comment: Depois de tanto esforço, é meio injusto vc desmarcar a minha resposta. Marcando a sua própria resposta vc não ganha nada e eu perco os 15pts. Inclusive foi a minha resposta q inspirou a sua.

Comment: Vc está correto, ainda estou aprendendo a usar a plataforma, não sei se faz alguma diferença agora mais remarquei a sua como a correta novamente.. desculpe quanto a isso, terei mais cuidado nas próximas publicações !

Answer (score 0):

Testei um pouco diferente e acabou funcionando.. segue o que foi feito:

```
<!-- aqui fica o conteúdo a ser formatado  -->
<div name="editor" id="editor" class="editor">Escreva seu texto...</div>

<!-- aqui é onde o conteúdo será enviado via POST -->
<form method="POST" action="?paginas=teste" name="form_redacao" id="form_redacao" onsubmit="return enviardados();" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>

  <!-- tag oculta que realiza a tarefa de enviar via POST -->
  <textarea name="redacao" id="redacao" style="display: none;"></textarea>        
  <br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-enviar" value="Mostrar Resultado">    
</form>

    <script> 
        /* converte o conteúdo da DIV em textarea e envia os dados via PSOT */

        $('#btn-enviar').click(function(){

            //trata o conteudo vindo da Div e o transfere para um textarea que fica ocluto.
            $("#redacao").text($("#editor").html().trim());

            //ativa a ação após dar o click no botão de enviar
            $('#form_redacao').submit();    
        });
    </script>
```